# Checking if an id exist in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a Customer table and an order table and i'm trying to check to make sure the customer in the order table exists in the customer table before i'm allowed to execute the rest of my script.

This is the code that's causing the problem,

```
    alter proc Order
  @CustomerID int
  as
Declare @CusID int


select @CusID = dbo.CustomerTable.CustomerID
 from dbo.CustomerTable
inner join dbo.OrdersTable
on dbo.CustomerTable.CustomerID
= dbo.OrdersTable.CustomerID
 where dbo.OrdersTable.CustomerID = @CustomerID

if(@CusID != @CustomerID)
 begin
raiserror('The customer does not exist')
return 1
end

 exec Order 44
```

When I try execute the script with a CustomerID that's not in the table it doesn't give me the error message. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[Order]  --<-- Avoid using key words for object names
@CustomerID int
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF NOT EXISTS
            (select 1
            from dbo.CustomerTable inner join dbo.OrdersTable
            on dbo.CustomerTable.CustomerID = dbo.OrdersTable.CustomerID
            where dbo.OrdersTable.CustomerID = @CustomerID)
 BEGIN
   RAISERROR('The customer does not exist', 16,1)
   RETURN 1
 END
    RETURN @CustomerID;
END
```

**EXECUTE PROC**

Since this procedure returns a value you will need to execute a little bit differently, something like

```
DECLARE @RtnValue INT;

EXECUTE @RtnValue =  dbo.[Order] 44

SELECT @RtnValue;    --<-- now you can use this value whatever you want to do with it
```

Comment: I had just finished typing in almost exactly the same thing when the "new answer" message appeared. Obviously you still need your "exec Order 44" in the proc.

Comment: The op was trying to execute the procedure itself if you see the names, both procedures are called `Order` :), I also thought it was another procedure call from inside the procedure but its not.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @CusID IS NULL
    BEGIN    
    raiserror('The customer does not exist', 0, 1)
    RETURN 1
    END
```